# CRUD with Angular 4 and Laravel

Tags: angular, laravel

I'm new to angular 4 and I created an api to get data from my database and show it or update it or create a new one. I know how to show data but I don't know how to update or create them. I created api.services.ts:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Article } from './../models/article';
import { Category } from './../models/category';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getAllArticle(pagenumber: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost/api/articles?page=' + pagenumber)
                    .map(res => res.json());
  }

  getArticle(slug: string): Observable<Article>{
    return this.http.get('http://localhost/api/article/' + slug)
      .map(res => res.json());
  } 

  getAllCategory(): Observable<Category[]>{
    return this.http.get('http://localhost/api/categories')
      .map(res => res.json()); 
  }

  getCategoryArticle(slug : string) : Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('http://localhost/api/article/category/' + slug)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

and I create single-article.component.ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../services/api.services';
import { Article } from '../models/article';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-single-article',
  templateUrl: '/../../templates/single-article.component.html',
  providers: [ApiService]
})
export class SingleArticleComponent implements OnInit {

  article: Article;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private api: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params
      .map((params: Params) => params['slug'])
      .switchMap(slug => this.api.getArticle(slug))
      .subscribe(article => this.article = article);
  }
}
```

to show data but I don't know how to create update-article.component.ts. How can I do that?

Comment: Please update your question with what you have tried so far.

Comment: You should consider to add more detail. How is your model and controller, if you are using resources from Laravel, and this kind of information would help you to get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change your `this.http.get('http://localhost/api/article/category/' + slug)` with `this.http.put('http://localhost/api/article/category/' + slug, data)`. Use PUT or POST method when call this.http and pass the object data as second parameter.